# Load image from URL - Java

Tags: java, android, image

I am trying to load an image from a url in the `handelResponse` of my ASYNC Task that makes a GET request, and in `handelResponse` I have this

```
 InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(homeScreenPicUrl).getContent();
 b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

But my ASYNC Task seems to have a problem with this as I get `W/System.err﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` how could I load the image in the `hadelResponse`, ideally I want to load it syncronously as I want to wait for it to load before moving to the next screen.

And since this is all happening on the splash screen I am just waiting for the pic before moving to the main page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `InputStream` is just a handler: when you `read()` from it (which is what `BitmapFactory` does) you are in fact fetching data from the network, and Android forbids it because you are slowing the system.

Either you decode the stream in the background thread and change the return type of the `AsyncTask` to `Bitmap`, or you store the content of the stream in a `byte[]` and use that `byte[]` to build the image in the UI thread. Both solution are equivalent because you are consuming the stream in the background thread and store its content in memory.

```
public byte[] consume(InputStream in) throws Exception {
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
  int read = -1;
  while ((read = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
  }
  return out.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Okay how do I take the input stream and turn it to a `byte[]`? And then could I pass the `byte[]` to the next activity?

Comment: Internet is full of examples. I've added a code sample

Comment: It still fails on this line when I try to make the input stream `InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(homeScreenUrl).getContent();`

Comment: Do you use an AsyncTask or no? Can you understand at least the big picture of your problem and post the relevant code? The method consume() must be run in the background thread